# convert data string to a csv format

Tags: python

i am organizing some data from one big string called aa and it conatin :

```
$print(aa)

"birthDate":"2010-01-21","tall":151,"weight":55.5,"showSize":41
,
"birthDate":"2011-05-21","tall":155,"weight":44.2,"showSize":42
,
"birthDate":"2012-11-27","tall":145,"weight":49.3,"showSize":43
,
```

...and go on like this

exactly like the above , i want to put it in csv where : 
birthDate ,tall ,weight and showSize are removed and the data only left like this :

```
2010-01-21 , 151 , 55.5 , 41  "\n "
2011-05-21 , 155 , 44.2 , 42  "\n "
2012-11-27 , 145 , 49.3 , 43  "\n "
```

Comment: Please run `print(repr(aa))` and put the output of that into your question. It's hard to tell exactly what's in `aa` from the output of `print(aa)` that now in it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just use

```
aa = aa.replace('"birthDate:"', "")
```

And so on.

---

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
aa = "'birthDate':'2010-01-21','tall':151,'weight':55.5,'showSize':41\n,\n'birthDate':'2011-05-21','tall':155,weight':44.2,'showSize':42\n,\n'birthDate':'2012-11-27','tall':145,'weight':49.3,'showSize':43\n,\n"
print("ORIGINAL>>>")
print(aa)

# Cleanup the input to change the separators.
bb = aa.replace("\n,", "")
print("MODIFIED>>>")
print(bb)

# Split the "big string" into a list of lines then iterate over them.
for line in bb.split():

    # Stop on the last line
    if len(line) == 0:
        break

    # For each line, split it into "key":"value" items.
    # Then split each item again to get the "value" part.
    # Store each "value" in a list.
    csv_cols = list()
    for item in line.split(","):
        csv_cols.append(item.split(":")[1])

    # Combine the list elements into a string.
    csv_row = ",".join(csv_cols)
    print(csv_row)
```

Output:

```
ORIGINAL>>>
'birthDate':'2010-01-21','tall':151,'weight':55.5,'showSize':41
,
'birthDate':'2011-05-21','tall':155,weight':44.2,'showSize':42
,
'birthDate':'2012-11-27','tall':145,'weight':49.3,'showSize':43
,

MODIFIED>>>
'birthDate':'2010-01-21','tall':151,'weight':55.5,'showSize':41
'birthDate':'2011-05-21','tall':155,weight':44.2,'showSize':42
'birthDate':'2012-11-27','tall':145,'weight':49.3,'showSize':43

'2010-01-21',151,55.5,41
'2011-05-21',155,44.2,42
'2012-11-27',145,49.3,43
```

Comment: @abdullahOmran Great. If it helped you, you can either upvote or click the checkmark to mark it as accepted. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).